# Set password on .APK

Tags: android, installation, apk

Is there a way to set a "permission" | any other method which prompts the user to enter a password to install .apk

thnx

Comment: Do you mean installing certain .APK or secure the whole phone from installing any .APKs ?

Comment: I mean securing a single .apk with out calling a web service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download the Android source code, and modify it to ask for a password before installing. You could filter apps based on their signature, and ask for the password only when a app matching a certain signature is installed.
2. Compromise a little bit, and ask for a password when your app runs, much like Facebook asks you to login.

Comment: 2. Yeah Im gonna have to do that..I already have a log in /registration screen for users..might have to modify this to be a password to access app..THNX

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.

The best way to protect your app is to implement an authentication system inside your app.

Comment: Yeah...thnx for the reply. Was wondering if I had missed anything on dev docs..guess not..thanx again